# How to calculate the rotation of a needle based on a value?

Tags: geometry, interpolation

I need to calculate the rotation of a needle in degrees or radians from a given value, specifically vertical speed of an airplane in feets per minute. The results should be like this:

Input value $\implies$ Result

$-1500 \implies -135$

$-1000 \implies -90$

$-500 \implies -45$

$0 \implies 0$

$500 \implies 45$

$1000 \implies 90$

$1500 \implies 135$

Can you please show me a formula how to do this ? I have no idea.

Comment: Please be a it more specific. "I need to calculate the rotation of a needle from a given value" does not specify enough information to help you.

Comment: @Lazy please read my whole post - below that I added an interpolation table showing what I mean.

Comment: I’ve read your whole post, but that does not explain what you actually want. If you want an interpolation of these values they appear to correlate linearly, so $y=45x/500$

Comment: @Lazy sorry, I'm not very familiar with high-level maths - but that formula was just what I needed ! If you make it an answer, I'll be happy to accept and upvote it ;)

Comment: It’s not really about high level maths, but about explaining what you want.

Comment: @Lazy okay, maybe, I'll try to do better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I’ve gathered what you want you want to have a linear transformation from altitute to rotation of a needle.

In that case the formula would look somewhat like
$$ y = kx + d \mod 360 $$
in degrees
$$ y = kx + d \mod 2\pi $$
for rad. In your case $d=0$ and $k=45/500=9/100$.

Here the notation $A \mod B$ means $A-[A/B]B$ where $[.]$ is the flooring function.

So your formula is basically
$$ y = 9/100\cdot x - [(9/100\cdot x) / 360]\cdot 360 = 9/10\cdot x - [x/4000]\cdot360 $$

Comment: Missed a 0, its $k=9/100$, not $k=9/10$.